# Packaging ipad app that supports internationalization

Tags: iphone, ipad, internationalization, iso

I need to build an app that supports internationalization (about 16 languages) and that contains a lot of images and text. What is the best way to package them? Should I have a separate application for each language or have just one that manages all languages when i distribute it in the app store.

This a more of an architectural  decision than a technical one.

Comment: If image varies with language, single app can cause size problem. But without that i can't think any advantage of separated apps, is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have a separate application for each language. Just create a file called Localizable.Strings. Tutorials: http://www.ibabbleon.com/iphone_app_localization.html and http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial

I hope that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the built in localization features. For text you can use the method `NSLocalizedString(@"blah", nil)`. You can also add a files that will work with this function to provide users with the correct language `Localizable.Strings`.

In iTunes connect there is the option to add different descriptions and screenshots for each of your chosen languages (setup manually through iTunes Connect). iTunes will also deal with all the pricing stuff which is nice.

Here is a [nice tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial) that should help you get started. One thing that you may come across as an issue is adding extra languages to the `Localizable.Strings` file, the way to do this easily is through Terminal (since Xcode won't let you drag and drop extra files into it for some reason).

Hope this helps.